# Custom LEDs from Raspberry Pi 3 with Retropie build?

Tags: retropie

I am creating a casing for my retro pi unit.

How can I program some LEDs using the IO ports to light up when the unit is switched on specifically on the retro pie distro?

Is it possible to create a simple script which will execute and keep running whilst the device has power?

I can see many tutorials on creating a program to light an LED in raspian, but how can I get this to run automatically on boot up in retropie?

Comment: I'm disappointed you haven't managed to find any information to help you.  It is widely available.  I'd start by looking through https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/

Comment: I am aware of the numerous tutorials online regarding the pi and simple led i/o programs. I expect I could create a program and run it in raspian. This question is specifically looking at the retro pie distro. How could I get a program running as part of booting of this distro...running in the background...not running manually by double clicking an executable.

Comment: My mistake.  I have no knowledge of Retropie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a script running continuously just to keep an LED on is going to use a lot of the Pi's ressources. Here are some alternatives:

1. Since you are talking about building a case and there is already a power LED on the Pi, include a light-conductive rod (clear acrylic might do) in your case to carry the light from the existing LED to the outside of your case.

   2. If you erally want to have your own LED (it does look better than a light conducting rod), just have your script run once at bootup (using the startup deamon of retroPi or cron) just to turn your LED on and make sure your script terminates and closes, then have a different script running once whenever a shutdown is in process using the shutdown system of retropi.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Sounds great.Can't wait to start the project. I'm converting an old 'dead' Amiga 500 by dying it 'black' and replacing the motherboard with the retro pie machine and using an old a1200 keyboard with keyrah so to have an integrated usb keyboard! :)